# Rails : Scaffold works for the first, but not for the second table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I am using aptana radrails
empty rail project :
 scaffold Article titre:string body:text categorie_id:integer ordre:integer
Migrate -> it works fine

scaffold Categorie titre:string ordre:integer

It generate the files but when i access http://127.0.0.1:3000/categories i have the following error :

NameError in Categories#index 
Showing app/views/categories/index.html.erb where line #22 raised:

undefined local variable or method `new_categorie_path' for #

Extracted source (around line #22):

19: 
20: 
21: 
22: <%= link_to 'New categorie', new_categorie_path %>

i deleted recreated my whole rails project a few times, changed categorie with another name but it keep failling. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Salil's answer which is correct, Rails convention is to have english like naming.

If you put

```
Categorie
```

in your scaffold Rails will not be able to pluralize it correctly in categories.

You can also try a different path using legacy names and no pluralization but it is a painful path.

I would advice to use english naming.

Comment: that's it, i did not knew rails was so tied with english.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
scaffold Category titre:string ordre:integer
```